# Unable to install nltk in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, nltk, dockerfile

I am trying to install nltk packages on docker, down below is my docker file

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

# COPY startup script into known file location in container
COPY start.sh /start.sh

RUN python -m libs.py

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD specifcies the command to execute to start the server running.
CMD ["/start.sh"]

# done!
```

**libs.py** contain the nltk packages, In requirement.txt **nltk==3.2.5** is installed

```
import nltk
nltk.data.path('libs/')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('pros_cons')
nltk.download('snowball_data')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru')
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('universal_tagset')
nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger')
nltk.download('hmm_treebank_pos_tagger')
nltk.download('reuters')
nltk.download('treebank')
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('porter_test')
nltk.download('rslp')
```

but it but it giving me error on docker image:

```
 File "/usr/src/app/training/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from src import main_file as main
  File "/usr/src/app/src/main_file.py", line 10, in <module>
    from src import aspects_from_correct_data as asp
  File "/usr/src/app/src/aspects_from_correct_data.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nltk.tag import pos_tag
  File "/usr/src/app/nltk.py", line 2, in <module>
    nltk.download('wordnet')
AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'download'
```

Comment: docker image created successfully but when In API call it giving me this error,                                                                                                            ` >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data''`

Comment: You should not call your file `nltk.py` if you also need to use the library `nltk`, since `import nltk` might resolve to that file instead of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Anaconda with `nltk==3.2.4` and I am not running Docker.

Your `libs.py` script works for me when I comment out the second line (`nltk.data.path('libs/')`). Per [`data` Module docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#module-nltk.data), `nltk.data.path` is a list, not a function.